# Error: syntax error in set_input_delay (Quartus)

Tags: syntax-error, verilog, quartus

The `Fmax` parameter in my code was reported as : `No Paths to report`. Therefore, I was trying to set input signal relationship with the defined clock using `set_input_delay`. However, the error report states:

> Verilog HDL Syntax error near text "-" ; expecting "." or "(".

I checked the documentation on the Intel website, and it shows that the correct syntax is:

**set_input_delay -clock clk 1.5 [get_ports myin]**

```
module DT2(a,b,c,f,e,g,newin,v,w,x,m,n,F1,r,N1,D1,p,q,j,n1,t,clk,new);

input clk;
input [10:0]new;

set_input_delay -clock clk 1.5 [get_ports new];

output reg [12:0]a;
output reg [11:0]b;
output reg [10:0]c,f,e,g,m,n,F1,r;
output reg [10:0]newin;
output reg [40:0]v;
output reg [30:0]w;
output reg [20:0]x,N1,D1,p,q,n1;
output reg [1:0]j;
output reg t;
integer i;




initial
begin
a=13'b100_1000011111; //3.10
b=12'b10_1110011110; // 2.10
c=11'b1_0000101010; //1.10

e=11'b0_0000100100; //1.10
f=11'b0_0010111100; //1.10
g=11'b0_0111000000; //1.10
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin
newin=new;
t=newin[10];
if(t==1'b1)
begin
newin=newin-11'b1_0000000000;
v = (newin*newin*newin*e);
w = (newin*newin*f); 
x = (newin*g);
m=(v[40:30])+(x[20:10])+(11'b0_0000000101);
n = m-(w[30:20]);
x=(n*n);
n=n<<1;
m=n-x[20:10];  //need to keep
n=n>>1;
n=(11'b1_0000000000)-n;
end

else
begin
v = (newin*newin*newin*a);
w = (newin*newin*b);
x = (newin*c);

m=(v[40:30])+(x[20:10])+(11'b0_0000001100);
n = m-(w[30:20]);
x=(n*n);
n=n<<1;
m=n+x[20:10];  //need to keep
n=n>>1;
n=(11'b1_0000000000)+n;

end


n1=(n*n);
//SHIFTING NONE

j=2'b00;
for(i=0;i<=16;i=i+1)
    begin
    if(j==2'b00)
        begin
        N1=m*(n1[20:10]);
        D1=(n1[20:10])*(n1[20:10]);
        F1=12'b10_0000000000-D1[20:10];
        j=2'b01;
        end
    else if(j==2'b01)
        begin
        p=F1*N1[20:10];
        q=F1*D1[20:10];
        r=12'b10_0000000000-D1[20:10];
        j=2'b10;
        end
    else if(j==2'b10)
        begin
        N1=r*p[20:10];
        D1=r*q[20:10];
        F1=12'b10_0000000000-D1[20:10];
        j=2'b01;
        end
        
    end

end


endmodule
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove the following line from your Verilog code because it is not legal Verilog syntax:

```
set_input_delay -clock clk 1.5 [get_ports new];
```

It looks like a command for your synthesis tool, and it likely belongs in a synthesis script.

Answer (score 0):

The statement **set_input_delay -clock clk 1.5 [get_ports myin]** as has been already stated, is not Verilog. It is a Synopsis Design Constraint.

In a Quartus project, a .sdc file is used to hold the timing constraints for the design. Your statement needs to go in there. During the build process this file is an input to the synthesis tool and fitter tool.